# Проблема с Pyinstaller (ошибка [Errno 22])

Tags: python, pyinstaller

Пытаюсь преобразовать проект в python в .exe. Запускаю процедуру стандартно через команду:

```
pyinstaller --onedir -w main.py
```

Доходит до OpenGL и выдает следующую ошибку:

```
1459 INFO: OpenGL_accelerate module loaded
1495 INFO: Using accelerated ArrayDatatype
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\utils\hooks\__init__.py", line 621, in collect_submodules
    modules, subpackages, on_error = isolated_python.call(_collect_submodules, name, on_error)
  File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\isolated\_parent.py", line 293, in call
    ok, output = loads(b64decode(self._read_handle.readline()))
EOFError: EOF read where object expected

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\runpy.py", line 196, in _run_module_as_main
    return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
  File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\runpy.py", line 86, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\Scripts\pyinstaller.exe\__main__.py", line 7, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\__main__.py", line 194, in _console_script_run
    run()
  File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\__main__.py", line 180, in run
    run_build(pyi_config, spec_file, **vars(args))
  File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\__main__.py", line 61, in run_build
    PyInstaller.building.build_main.main(pyi_config, spec_file, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\build_main.py", line 978, in main
    build(specfile, distpath, workpath, clean_build)
  File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\build_main.py", line 900, in build
    exec(code, spec_namespace)
  File "C:\Users\HP\Desktop\project\rx-analize\main.spec", line 7, in <module>
    a = Analysis(
  File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\build_main.py", line 424, in __init__
    self.__postinit__()
  File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\datastruct.py", line 173, in __postinit__
    self.assemble()
  File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\build_main.py", line 576, in assemble
    priority_scripts.append(self.graph.add_script(script))
  File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\depend\analysis.py", line 269, in add_script
    self._top_script_node = super().add_script(pathname)
  File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\lib\modulegraph\modulegraph.py", line 1433, in add_script
    self._process_imports(n)
  File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\lib\modulegraph\modulegraph.py", line 2850, in _process_imports
    target_modules = self._safe_import_hook(*import_info, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\depend\analysis.py", line 433, in _safe_import_hook
    return super()._safe_import_hook(target_module_partname, source_module, target_attr_names, level, edge_attr)
  File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\lib\modulegraph\modulegraph.py", line 2301, in _safe_import_hook
    target_modules = self.import_hook(
  File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\lib\modulegraph\modulegraph.py", line 1505, in import_hook
    target_package, target_module_partname = self._find_head_package(
  File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\lib\modulegraph\modulegraph.py", line 1684, in _find_head_package
    target_package = self._safe_import_module(
  File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\depend\analysis.py", line 480, in _safe_import_module
    return super()._safe_import_module(module_basename, module_name, parent_package)
  File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\lib\modulegraph\modulegraph.py", line 2062, in _safe_import_module
    self._process_imports(n)
  File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\lib\modulegraph\modulegraph.py", line 2850, in _process_imports
    target_modules = self._safe_import_hook(*import_info, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\depend\analysis.py", line 433, in _safe_import_hook
    return super()._safe_import_hook(target_module_partname, source_module, target_attr_names, level, edge_attr)
  File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\lib\modulegraph\modulegraph.py", line 2301, in _safe_import_hook
    target_modules = self.import_hook(
  File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\lib\modulegraph\modulegraph.py", line 1505, in import_hook
    target_package, target_module_partname = self._find_head_package(
  File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\lib\modulegraph\modulegraph.py", line 1684, in _find_head_package
    target_package = self._safe_import_module(
  File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\depend\analysis.py", line 480, in _safe_import_module
    return super()._safe_import_module(module_basename, module_name, parent_package)
  File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\lib\modulegraph\modulegraph.py", line 2062, in _safe_import_module
    self._process_imports(n)
  File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\lib\modulegraph\modulegraph.py", line 2850, in _process_imports
    target_modules = self._safe_import_hook(*import_info, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\depend\analysis.py", line 369, in _safe_import_hook
    excluded_imports = self._find_all_excluded_imports(source_module.identifier)
  File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\depend\analysis.py", line 357, in _find_all_excluded_imports
    excluded_imports.update(module_hook.excludedimports)
  File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\depend\imphook.py", line 316, in __getattr__
    self._load_hook_module()
  File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\depend\imphook.py", line 383, in _load_hook_module
    self._hook_module = importlib_load_source(self.hook_module_name, self.hook_filename)
  File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\compat.py", line 612, in importlib_load_source
    return mod_loader.load_module()
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 548, in _check_name_wrapper
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 1063, in load_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 888, in load_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 290, in _load_module_shim
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 719, in _load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 688, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 883, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 241, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\_pyinstaller_hooks_contrib\hooks\stdhooks\hook-pyqtgraph.py", line 34, in <module>
    all_imports = collect_submodules("pyqtgraph")
  File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\utils\hooks\__init__.py", line 617, in collect_submodules
    with isolated.Python() as isolated_python:
  File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\isolated\_parent.py", line 247, in __exit__
    self._write_handle.flush()
OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument
```

Находил в ответах, что решением данной проблемы являются переустановка `pywin32` и добавление скриптов в исключения антивируса. Однако, все это не помогло. Пытался откатить pyinstaller до предыдущих версий, но тогда появляется проблема с подключением numpy `WARNING: Several hooks defined for module 'numpy'. Please take care they do not conflict`.

Заранее спасибо всем.

Comment: Ошибка похоже про hooks, попробуйте их обновить `pip install -U pyinstaller-hooks-contrib`

Comment: @DiMithras ошибка сохраняется. Проблема скорее всего в модуле `PyOpenGL` который я нигде не использую в коде (хотя pyinstaller похоже считает наоборот)

Comment: не изучал OpenGL на Python, но если какая-то библиотека от него зависит и использует готовый бинарник, возможно pyinstaller пытается собрать из исходников, в таком случае стоит подзаморочиться с build tools и поставить всё по максимуму.

Comment: @DiMithras проблема решена простым удалением пакетов OpenGL и Jupyter и сборкой проекта на другом ПК

Comment: Можно просто исключить не нужные библиотеки.

Comment: @Александр которых нет.